# Prevent sms from going to outbox

Tags: android, sms

I am making an app that sends an SMS programmatically. 
I don't want it to pop up in the built in SMS app.
Incoming SMS doesn't matter for now.

Is there a way to prevent an sms from going to the 'outbox'?

This is how I send:

```
SmsManager sms = SmsManager.getDefault();
sms.sendTextMessage(phoneNumber, null, message, sentPI, deliveredPI);
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

After KitKat, no. See the post here: http://android-developers.blogspot.com/2013/10/getting-your-sms-apps-ready-for-kitkat.html

Before KitKat, it won't go to the "Outbox" so it isn't an issue.

You can try a third-party solution like www.superdupersms.com (that's the only one I know of, and I'm a part of the development team).